# Custom header and banking body style mixed in moderncv

Tags: moderncv

I have some experience on LaTeX, but I have never tried to modify templates. I have been working over some previous questions, but I have not enough knowledge in the field.

I would like to mix a custom header with the banking body in moderncv. I would like something easy for the header, but not so big, to reduce the space needed and to avoid having two pages of CV for just two or three lines. I have used the answers from [classic title and banking body style mixed (moderncv)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146770/classic-title-and-banking-body-style-mixed-moderncv) , but I could not get any acceptable result.

I have thought in getting something like this in the header:
[image]

Any idea or advice of how to start the learning flow from the beginning, or both?

The code used is:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}   
\moderncvstyle{banking}                        
\moderncvcolor{blue}                          
\nopagenumbers{}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\makeatletter


\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{p{3.1cm}l@{}r}%
      {\bfseries #4, \bfseries #5} \\%
      {\itshape #2} & {\itshape #3\ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}}& \\%
  \end{tabular*}%
  \ifx&#7&%
    \else{\\\vbox{$\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad$\small#7}}\fi%
  \par\addvspace{#1}
}

%\renewcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{%
%  \cvitem[#1]{#4}{%
%    {\bfseries#5}%
%   \newline
%    \ifthenelse{\equal{#2}{}}{}{ {\slshape#2}}% ... into this one (without comma).
%    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{ #6}%
%    \newline
%    .\strut%
%    \ifx&#7&%
%      \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}\fi}}
%%%%






\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{28}{30}\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\titlefont}{\LARGE\mdseries\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\addressfont}{\small\mdseries\normalfont}
\renewcommand*{\quotefont}{\large\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\sectionfont}{\Large\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionfont}{\large\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\hintfont}{}

% styles
\renewcommand*{\namestyle}[1]{{\namefont\textcolor{color0}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\titlestyle}[1]{{\titlefont\textcolor{color2}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\addressstyle}[1]{{\addressfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\quotestyle}[1]{{\quotefont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\sectionstyle}[1]{{\sectionfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionstyle}[1]{{\subsectionfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\hintstyle}[1]{{\hintfont\textcolor{color0}{#1}}}
%
\newlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}
\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{0pt}% dummy value
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  % optional detailed information box
  \newbox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}{%
    \addressfont\color{color2}%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}r@{}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity will always be defined but could be empty
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@mobile}}{}{\makenewline\@mobile}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@phone}}{}{\makenewline\@phone}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@fax}}{}{\makenewline\@fax}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emaillink{\@email}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\httplink{\@homepage}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
    \end{tabular}
  }%
  % optional photo (pre-rendering)
  \newbox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
    {}%
    {%
      \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
      \color{color1}%
      \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%
      \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
      \framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}}%
  % name and title
  \newlength{\makecvtitledetailswidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitledetailswidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}%
  \newlength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt}}% check for dummy value (equivalent to \ifdim\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt)
    {\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{\textwidth-\makecvtitledetailswidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth}}%
    {}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\makecvtitlenamewidth}%
    \namestyle{\@firstname\ \@familyname}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\titlestyle{\@title}}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \hfill%
  % detailed information
  \llap{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of makecvtitlenamewidth is forced
  % optional photo (rendering)
  \usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}\\[2.5em]%
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}% to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \makecvtitle

\makeatother

% personal data
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
%\title{Resumé title}                          % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\address{street and number}{postcode city}    % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\mobile{+1~(234)~567~890}                     % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\phone{+2~(345)~678~901}                      % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\fax{+3~(456)~789~012}                        % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\email{john@doe.org}                          % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}                    % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\extrainfo{additional information}            % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{picture}                  % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; '64pt' is the height the picture must be resized to, 0.4pt is the thickness of the frame around it (put it to 0pt for no frame) and 'picture' is the name of the picture file
%\quote{`` A witty and playful quote''}                            % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted

% to show numerical labels in the bibliography (default is to show no labels); only useful if you make citations in your resume
%\makeatletter
%\renewcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
%\makeatother

% bibliography with mutiple entries
%\usepackage{multibib}
%\newcites{book,misc}{{Books},{Others}}
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
%\begin{CJK*}{UTF8}{gbsn}                     % to typeset your resume in Chinese using CJK
%-----       resume       ---------------------------------------------------------
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description line 1\newline{}Description line 2}
\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}

\section{Languages}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 1}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 2}{Skill level}{Comment}
\cvitemwithcomment{Language 3}{Skill level}{Comment}

\section{Computer skills}
\cvdoubleitem{category 1}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 4}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 2}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 5}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}
\cvdoubleitem{category 3}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}{category 6}{XXX, YYY, ZZZ}

\section{Interests}
\cvitem{hobby 1}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 2}{Description}
\cvitem{hobby 3}{Description}

\section{Extra 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 1}
\cvlistitem{Item 2}
\cvlistitem{Item 3}

\renewcommand{\listitemsymbol}{-~}            % change the symbol for lists

\section{Extra 2}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 1}{Item 4}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 2}{Item 5\cite{book1}}
\cvlistdoubleitem{Item 3}{}

% Publications from a BibTeX file without multibib
%  for numerical labels: \renewcommand{\bibliographyitemlabel}{\@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}}}
%  to redefine the heading string ("Publications"): \renewcommand{\refname}{Articles}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{publications}                   % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file

% Publications from a BibTeX file using the multibib package
%\section{Publications}
%\nocitebook{book1,book2}
%\bibliographystylebook{plain}
%\bibliographybook{publications}              % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file
%\nocitemisc{misc1,misc2,misc3}
%\bibliographystylemisc{plain}
%\bibliographymisc{publications}              % 'publications' is the name of a BibTeX file

\clearpage
%-----       letter       ---------------------------------------------------------
% recipient data
\recipient{Company Recruitment team}{Company, Inc.\\123 somestreet\\some city}
\date{January 01, 1984}
\opening{Dear Sir or Madam,}
\closing{Yours faithfully,}
\enclosure[Attached]{curriculum vit\ae{}}     % use an optional argument to use a string other than "Enclosure", or redefine \enclname
\makelettertitle

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis ullamcorper neque sit amet lectus facilisis sed luctus nisl iaculis. Vivamus at neque arcu, sed tempor quam. Curabitur pharetra tincidunt tincidunt. Morbi volutpat feugiat mauris, quis tempor neque vehicula volutpat. Duis tristique justo vel massa fermentum accumsan. Mauris ante elit, feugiat vestibulum tempor eget, eleifend ac ipsum. Donec scelerisque lobortis ipsum eu vestibulum. Pellentesque vel massa at felis accumsan rhoncus.

Suspendisse commodo, massa eu congue tincidunt, elit mauris pellentesque orci, cursus tempor odio nisl euismod augue. Aliquam adipiscing nibh ut odio sodales et pulvinar tortor laoreet. Mauris a accumsan ligula. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Suspendisse vulputate sem vehicula ipsum varius nec tempus dui dapibus. Phasellus et est urna, ut auctor erat. Sed tincidunt odio id odio aliquam mattis. Donec sapien nulla, feugiat eget adipiscing sit amet, lacinia ut dolor. Phasellus tincidunt, leo a fringilla consectetur, felis diam aliquam urna, vitae aliquet lectus orci nec velit. Vivamus dapibus varius blandit.

Duis sit amet magna ante, at sodales diam. Aenean consectetur porta risus et sagittis. Ut interdum, enim varius pellentesque tincidunt, magna libero sodales tortor, ut fermentum nunc metus a ante. Vivamus odio leo, tincidunt eu luctus ut, sollicitudin sit amet metus. Nunc sed orci lectus. Ut sodales magna sed velit volutpat sit amet pulvinar diam venenatis.

Albert Einstein discovered that $e=mc^2$ in 1905.

\[ e=\lim_{n \to \infty} \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n \]

\makeletterclosing

%\clearpage\end{CJK*}                         % if you are typesetting your resume in Chinese using CJK; the \clearpage is required for fancyhdr to work correctly with CJK, though it kills the page numbering by making \lastpage undefined
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post some code. People like me have severe starting trouble (read as very lazy) and hence need some help. :)

Comment: I have not posted code, because all I made has been to take the solution from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/146778/91082 and modifying it to solve my problems. But if you need it, I will copy what I modified on it, that is not so much. Please, check now the edited post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it by modifying the answer given in the link:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{34}{36}\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\titlefont}{\LARGE\mdseries\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\addressfont}{\small\mdseries\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\quotefont}{\large\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\sectionfont}{\Large\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionfont}{\large\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\hintfont}{}

% styles
\renewcommand*{\namestyle}[1]{{\namefont\textcolor{color0}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\titlestyle}[1]{{\titlefont\textcolor{color2}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\addressstyle}[1]{{\addressfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\quotestyle}[1]{{\quotefont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\sectionstyle}[1]{{\sectionfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionstyle}[1]{{\subsectionfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\hintstyle}[1]{{\hintfont\textcolor{color0}{#1}}}
%
\newlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}
\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{0pt}% dummy value
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  % optional detailed information box
  \newbox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}{%
    \addressfont\color{color2}%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity will always be defined but could be empty
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@mobile}}{}{\makenewline\mobilesymbol\@mobile}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@phone}}{}{\makenewline\phonesymbol\@phone}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@fax}}{}{\makenewline\faxsymbol\@fax}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
    \end{tabular}
  }%
  % optional photo (pre-rendering)
  \newbox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
    {}%
    {%
      \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
      \color{color1}%
      \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%
      \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
      \framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}}%
  % name and title
  \newlength{\makecvtitledetailswidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitledetailswidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}%
  \newlength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt}}% check for dummy value (equivalent to \ifdim\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt)
    {\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{\textwidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth}}%
    {}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
    \namestyle{\@firstname\ \@familyname}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\titlestyle{\@title}}
    \\
    \usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}
    \end{tabular}
    \hfill
    \begin{adjustbox}{valign=T}
      \usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}
    \end{adjustbox}
  \end{minipage}%
  \par\vspace{2.5em}
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}%
\makeatother

% personal data
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{Resume title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}
\mobile{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone{+2~(345)~678~901}
\fax{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[94pt][0.4pt]{picture}
\quote{`` A witty and playful quote''}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description line 1\newline{}Description line 2}
\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

Here is a more compact version:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{blue}

\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{34}{36}\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\titlefont}{\LARGE\mdseries\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\addressfont}{\small\mdseries\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\quotefont}{\large\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\sectionfont}{\Large\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionfont}{\large\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\hintfont}{}

% styles
\renewcommand*{\namestyle}[1]{{\namefont\textcolor{color0}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\titlestyle}[1]{{\titlefont\textcolor{color2}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\addressstyle}[1]{{\addressfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\quotestyle}[1]{{\quotefont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\sectionstyle}[1]{{\sectionfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionstyle}[1]{{\subsectionfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\hintstyle}[1]{{\hintfont\textcolor{color0}{#1}}}
%
\newlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}
\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{0pt}% dummy value
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  % optional detailed information box
  \newbox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}{%
    \addressfont\color{color2}%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet,%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\hspace{1ex} \@addresscity}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity will always be defined but could be empty
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@mobile}}{}{\makenewline\mobilesymbol\@mobile}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@phone}}{}{\hspace{1.5em} \phonesymbol\@phone}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@fax}}{}{\makenewline\faxsymbol\@fax}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\hspace{1.5em}\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
    \end{tabular}
  }%
  % optional photo (pre-rendering)
  \newbox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
    {}%
    {%
      \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
      \color{color1}%
      \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%
      \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
      \framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}}%
  % name and title
  \newlength{\makecvtitledetailswidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitledetailswidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}%
  \newlength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt}}% check for dummy value (equivalent to \ifdim\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt)
    {\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{\textwidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth}}%
    {}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}%
    \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
    \namestyle{\@firstname\ \@familyname}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\titlestyle{\@title}}
    \\
    \usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}
    \end{tabular}
    \hfill
    \begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}
      \usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}
    \end{adjustbox}
  \end{minipage}%
  \par\vspace{1em}
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[1em]}}%
  \par}%
\makeatother

% personal data
\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\title{Resume title}
\address{street and number}{postcode city}
\mobile{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone{+2~(345)~678~901}
\fax{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}
\homepage{www.johndoe.com}
\extrainfo{additional information}
\photo[94pt][0.4pt]{picture}
\quote{`` A witty and playful quote''}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Education}
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}  % arguments 3 to 6 can be left empty
\cventry{year--year}{Degree}{Institution}{City}{\textit{Grade}}{Description}

\section{Master thesis}
\cvitem{title}{\emph{Title}}
\cvitem{supervisors}{Supervisors}
\cvitem{description}{Short thesis abstract}

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description line 1\newline{}Description line 2}
\subsection{Miscellaneous}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{Description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It is very useful, because it helps me to change other parameters I need. But I still have a problem. The distance between the beginning of the page and the Name is still to big. Is there any way to reduce it like one or one and a half centimeter?

Comment: @Sergikito: It is the top margin. Reduce it using `geometry` package.

Answer (score 0):

I manged to get the answer above to work with modern cv in its newer version.
However i would like to change the Title back to the normal banking format.

John Doe | REsume title

and add the ability to use the new social tags for linkedin etc..

Would anybody have a hint how to do this?

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{34}{36}\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\titlefont}{\LARGE\mdseries\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\addressfont}{\small\mdseries\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\quotefont}{\large\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\sectionfont}{\Large\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionfont}{\large\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\hintfont}{}

% styles
\renewcommand*{\namestyle}[1]{{\namefont\textcolor{color0}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\titlestyle}[1]{{\titlefont\textcolor{color2}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\addressstyle}[1]{{\addressfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\quotestyle}[1]{{\quotefont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\sectionstyle}[1]{{\sectionfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionstyle}[1]{{\subsectionfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\hintstyle}[1]{{\hintfont\textcolor{color0}{#1}}}
%
\newlength{\makecvheadnamewidth}
\setlength{\makecvheadnamewidth}{0pt}% dummy value
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
    % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
    \recomputecvlengths%
    % optional detailed information box
    \newbox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}%
    \savebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}{%
        \addressfont\color{color2}%
        \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}%
            \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet,%
                \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\hspace{1ex} \@addresscity}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity will always be defined but could be empty
            \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@mobile}}{}{\makenewline\mobilesymbol\@mobile}%
            \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@phone}}{}{\hspace{1.5em} \phonesymbol\@phone}%
            \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@fax}}{}{\makenewline\faxsymbol\@fax}%
            \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
            \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@fax}}{}{\makenewline\faxsymbol\@fax}%
            \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\hspace{1.5em}\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
            \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
        \end{tabular}
    }%
    % optional photo (pre-rendering)
    \newbox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
    \savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
        {}%
        {%
            \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
            \color{color1}%
            \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%
            \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
            \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
            \framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}}%
    % name and title
    \newlength{\makecvtitledetailswidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitledetailswidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}%
    \newlength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
    \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\makecvheadnamewidth=0pt}}% check for dummy value (equivalent to \ifdim\makecvheadnamewidth=0pt)
    {\setlength{\makecvheadnamewidth}{\textwidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth}}%
    {}%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{\textwidth}%
        \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l}
            \namestyle{\@firstname\ \@familyname}%
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\titlestyle{\@title}}
            \\
            \usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}
        \end{tabular}
        \hfill
        \begin{adjustbox}{valign=t}
            \usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}
        \end{adjustbox}
    \end{minipage}%
    \par\vspace{1em}
    % optional quote
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[1em]}}%
    \par}%
\makeatother
```