# Position of Application Photo in moderncv

Tags: spacing, moderncv

I try to make a CV in the documentclass `moderncv`.

The style is a mix of `classic` and `banking` (based on the answer to [classic title and banking body style mixed (moderncv)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/146770/classic-title-and-banking-body-style-mixed-moderncv)). The problem is that I can not change the position of my application photo.

I would like to put the bottom of the picture on the bottom of the line *Nationalität*:
[image]

Ideally, I would like to be able to do little adjustments regarding the position myself. Does anyone know how to adjust the application photo?

Edit1: **MWE**

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}   
\moderncvstyle{banking}                        
\moderncvcolor{black}                          

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} %dt. Silbentrennung
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc} %Richtiges Sprach-Funktionieren am \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% T1 font encoding for high quality font output


\usepackage[scale=0.85,top=1cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{34}{36}\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\titlefont}{\LARGE\mdseries\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\addressfont}{\small\mdseries\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\quotefont}{\large\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\sectionfont}{\Large\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionfont}{\large\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\hintfont}{}

% styles
\renewcommand*{\namestyle}[1]{{\namefont\textcolor{color0}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\titlestyle}[1]{{\titlefont\textcolor{color2}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\addressstyle}[1]{{\addressfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\quotestyle}[1]{{\quotefont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\sectionstyle}[1]{{\sectionfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionstyle}[1]{{\subsectionfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\hintstyle}[1]{{\hintfont\textcolor{color0}{#1}}}
%
\newlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}
\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{0pt}% dummy value
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  % optional detailed information box
  \newbox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}{%
    \addressfont\color{color2}%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}r@{}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity will always be defined but could be empty
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@mobile}}{}{\makenewline\mobilesymbol\@mobile}%
%      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@phone}}{}{\makenewline\phonesymbol\@phone}%
%      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@fax}}{}{\makenewline\faxsymbol\@fax}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
    \end{tabular}
  }%
  % optional photo (pre-rendering)
  \newbox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
    {}%
    {%
      \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
      \color{color1}%
      \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%
      \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
      \framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}}%
  % name and title
  \newlength{\makecvtitledetailswidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitledetailswidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}%
  \newlength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt}}% check for dummy value (equivalent to \ifdim\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt)
    {\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{\textwidth-\makecvtitledetailswidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth}}%
    {}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\makecvtitlenamewidth}%
    \namestyle{\@firstname\ \@familyname}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\titlestyle{\@title}}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \hfill%
  % detailed information
  \llap{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of makecvtitlenamewidth is forced
  % optional photo (rendering)
  \usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}\\[2.5em]%
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}% to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \makecvtitle

\makeatother

% personal data
\name{Philip}{Mustertann \hspace{10mm} \large{Curriculum Vitae}}
%\title{Curriculum Vitae}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\address{Musterstr. 88}{40000 Musterdorf}    % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\phone[mobile]{0157 11111111}                   % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\phone[fixed]{01234 123456}                    % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}                      % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\email{Mustermann.Klausi@gmail.com}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\homepage{www.mustermus-mustermust.de}                         % optional, 
\extrainfo{\textbf{Geburtsdatum}: 24. März 1992 \\ \textbf{Nationalität}: Deutsch}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{ZBewerbung}                  % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted; '64pt' is the height the picture must be resized to, 0.4pt is the thickness of the frame around it (put it to 0pt for no frame) and 'picture' is the name of the picture file

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\makecvtitle}{{minipage}[t]}{{minipage}[]}{}{}
\patchcmd{\makecvtitle}{{tabular}[b]}{{tabular}}{}{}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\vspace{-40pt}
\section{Berufserfahrung}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think we really need some code from you to get started.  Ideally, a minimum working example (MWE).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the used image it cold be ugly to have the bottom of the image on the bottom of the line "Nationalität".  Better would be to center the image, then you will get a more harmonic look of the header.

For the following MWE I used an example image `example-image-10x16` from package [MWE](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mwe) to show a possible solution.

I added an environment `tabular` with centered output to your code:

```
  \savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
    {}%
    {%
      \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
      \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}r@{}}% <====================================
      \color{color1}%
      \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%
      \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
      \framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}%
      \end{tabular} % <=================================================
    }%
  }%
```

The command `\photo` I changed to

```
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-10x16} % ZBewerbung
```

With the following MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{banking}
\moderncvcolor{black}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} %dt. Silbentrennung
\usepackage[applemac]{inputenc} %Richtiges Sprach-Funktionieren am \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}% T1 font encoding for high quality font output


\usepackage[scale=0.85,top=1cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\namefont}{\fontsize{34}{36}\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\titlefont}{\LARGE\mdseries\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\addressfont}{\small\mdseries\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\quotefont}{\large\slshape}
\renewcommand*{\sectionfont}{\Large\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionfont}{\large\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand*{\hintfont}{}

% styles
\renewcommand*{\namestyle}[1]{{\namefont\textcolor{color0}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\titlestyle}[1]{{\titlefont\textcolor{color2}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\addressstyle}[1]{{\addressfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\quotestyle}[1]{{\quotefont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\sectionstyle}[1]{{\sectionfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\subsectionstyle}[1]{{\subsectionfont\textcolor{color1}{#1}}}
\renewcommand*{\hintstyle}[1]{{\hintfont\textcolor{color0}{#1}}}
%
\newlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}
\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{0pt}% dummy value
\renewcommand*{\makecvtitle}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  % optional detailed information box
  \newbox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}% 
  \savebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}{%
    \addressfont\color{color2}%
    \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}r@{}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity will always be defined but could be empty
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@mobile}}{}{\makenewline\mobilesymbol\@mobile}%
%      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@phone}}{}{\makenewline\phonesymbol\@phone}%
%      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@fax}}{}{\makenewline\faxsymbol\@fax}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
      \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
    \end{tabular}
  }%
  % optional photo (pre-rendering)
  \newbox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
    {}%
    {%
      \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}%
      \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}r@{}}% <====================================
      \color{color1}%
      \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%
      \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
        \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
      \framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}%
      \end{tabular} % <=================================================
    }%
  }%
  % name and title
  \newlength{\makecvtitledetailswidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitledetailswidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}%
  \newlength{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}\settowidth{\makecvtitlepicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}}%
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt}}% check for dummy value (equivalent to \ifdim\makecvtitlenamewidth=0pt)
    {\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{\textwidth-\makecvtitledetailswidth-\makecvtitlepicturewidth}}%
    {}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{\makecvtitlenamewidth}%
    \namestyle{\@firstname\ \@familyname}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\titlestyle{\@title}}%
  \end{minipage}%
  \hfill%
  % detailed information
  \llap{\usebox{\makecvtitledetailsbox}}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of makecvtitlenamewidth is forced
  % optional photo (rendering)
  \usebox{\makecvtitlepicturebox}\\[2.5em]%
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}% to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \makecvtitle

\makeatother

% personal data
\name{Philip}{Mustertann \hspace{10mm} \large{Curriculum Vitae}}
%\title{Curriculum Vitae}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\address{Musterstr. 88}{40000 Musterdorf}    % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\phone[mobile]{0157 11111111}                   % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\phone[fixed]{01234 123456}                    % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
%\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}                      % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\email{Mustermann.Klausi@gmail.com}                               % optional, remove / comment the line if not wanted
\homepage{www.mustermus-mustermust.de}                         % optional, 
\extrainfo{\textbf{Geburtsdatum}: 24. März 1992 \\ \textbf{Nationalität}: Deutsch}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-10x16} % ZBewerbung 

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\makecvtitle}{{minipage}[t]}{{minipage}[]}{}{}
\patchcmd{\makecvtitle}{{tabular}[b]}{{tabular}}{}{}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\vspace{-40pt}
\section{Berufserfahrung}
\end{document}
```

I get with an current version 2.0.0 of `moderncv` and current MiKTeX the following result:

[image: new header with centered photo]